# Get query execution time of Oracle with Python

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

I'm developing an application in Python that connects to an Oracle database, sends queries and has to record query response times. The library that I use to make the connection between Python and Oracle is cx_Oracle.
This is an example of code that I do (after establishing the connection):

```
test = self.cursor.execute("select * from company")
for row in self.cursor:
    print(row[0])
```

In this way I get the results of the query, but how do I get the response time in milliseconds?
Unfortunately on the internet I have not found a way to record query response times.
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
before = time()
cursor.execute("select * from db.customer")
after = time()
print after-before
```

i am not sure if that is exactly what you are looking for but hope it helps, don't forget to import time

```
from time import time
```

Answer (score 0):

by datetime

```
import datetime
startTime = datetime.datetime.today()
print("test")
endTime = datetime.datetime.today()
print(endTime - startTime)
```

or just use *timeit* lib

```
import timeit
timeit.timeit('print("test")', number=100)
```